# Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode error DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a frustrating issue where I have a really simple grid which crashes the application with the error below if I press CTRL C to copy to the clipboard

Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute

This is a Winforms application and I **do** have [STAThread] at the top of my main method

This is causing me a lot of issues and I have no direct control over the logic within the DataGridView which seems to be causing this

Is there a workaround?

This could be related to the presence of some async code in the form that is a parent to this one

When I try to reproduce this in an application that doesnt use async CTRL C works fine

I always do .ConfigureAwait(false) on all await calls so I dont really know what else I can do?

The exception callstack is shown below (with form and method names obscured for confidentiality)

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException
  HResult=0x80131520
  Message=Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessInsertKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Ctrade.DevTools.Ui.DetailForm.xxxx_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in mycode:line 222
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at xxx.MainForm.<button_Click>d__7.MoveNext() in My main form.cs:line 56

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    xxx.button_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in DetailForm.cs
    [External Code]
    xxx.button_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in MainForm.cs
```

Comment: Do you have a callstack for the exception? (Check event viewer if unhandled).

Comment: Please supply a [mcve].

Comment: So you're opening a modal dialog in an async method, specifying `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the method call. Do you know what `ConfigureAwait(false)` is doing, here? What is the use of an async method when showing a modal dialog? Are you trying to keep both forms (parent form and the modal one) active at the same time?

Comment: I tend to put ConfigureAwait false in all my Async calls. I want the modal one to have focus

Comment: Why do you *tend to put `ConfigureAwait(false)` in all your async calls*? Did you read somewhere that setting `false` can do some kind of magic? Well, it doesn't. It *can* be useful (or even necessary), but not when used blindly and not in every context. *I want the modal one to have focus*: what is preventing a modal dialog to have focus? Do you have more than one modal dialog around?

Comment: I hadn’t noticed any issues with the modal side of things but that was the fix. I removed ConfigureAwait(false) from the call before show dialog.